# After deleting element from the xml, XDocument adds a line at the end

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I am deleting element from xml with this code below;

```
StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile MyFile = await localFolder.GetFileAsync("CustomTV.xml");
var stream4 = await MyFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
XDocument myXml2 = XDocument.Load(stream4);
myXml2.Element("channelLists")
               .Elements("channellist")
               .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("lname") == lnameselectedText)
               .Remove();
using (var stream = await (await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("CustomTV.xml", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists)).OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
{
    myXml2.Save(stream.AsStreamForWrite());
}
```

before the delete the element with attribute "lname=name3";

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<channelLists>
<channellist lname="name1" />
<channellist lname="name2" />
<channellist lname="name3" />
<channellist lname="name4" />
</channelLists>
```

after deletion;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<channelLists>
<channellist lname="name1" />
<channellist lname="name2" />
<channellist lname="name4" />
</channelLists>lname="name4"/> //It adds all the time this line with last elements attribute.
</channelLists>
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your code writes modified XML on top of the original XML. That's why you see reminder of the original XML which located beyond the extend of the modified XML :

```
lname="name4"/>
</channelLists>
```

That said, [`CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.creationcollisionoption.aspx) might be more appropriate in this case.

Comment: i think that is the reason, but this time i get "access denied" alert on debug.

Comment: Close the stream that was used to load the existing xml before writing the modified xml?

Comment: Edit: I added "stream4.Dispose();" line after "XDocument myXml2 = XDocument.Load(stream4);" and did what @har07 said, problem solved.